# Drawing solid line in pandas dataframe every time column value changes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, styles

I'd like to draw a solid line in my pandas dataframe everytime a value in column "product_basket" resets.

This is how my df looks like:

[image]

What I'd like it to be is:

[image]

Pls feel free to suggest also other ideas in order to achieve a similar result.

Thanks in advance,

Stefano

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first get the indices where the `product_basket` isn't the same as the next one, and apply `border-bottom` CSS styling for the rows whose indices match them:

```
# `different` is a boolean series, we get the indices where it is True
different = df.product_basket.ne(df.product_basket.shift(-1))
inds = different[different].index

# for each row, `row.name` gives the index and if the condition is OK,
# we return a styling for the entire row with `len(row)`; else None
df.style.apply(lambda row: ["border-bottom: 2px solid blue;"]*len(row)
                           if row.name in inds
                           else [""]*len(row), axis=1)
```

With some sample data

[image]

Comment: When I try to do that, i get:

ValueError: Function <function <lambda> at 0x7f9f6c5a6aa0> returned the wrong shape.
Result has shape: (18,)
Expected shape:   (18, 4)

so supposingly the lambda function is returning a shape that has only the len of row but not columns? as a matter of fact, my df has a dimension of 18 rows * 4 columns....

Comment: @StefanoPuccini I edited the answer, need to return empty string of same size for the else part, too. Hope it works now.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the index of last row of a group using shift and boolean operations like so

**Code:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"product_basket":["CAT","CAT","CAT","CAT","FUR","FUR","FUR","FUR","HYG","HYG"]})

df['last_of_group'] = (df['product_basket'].shift() != df['product_basket']).shift(-1).fillna(False)

print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
  product_basket  last_of_group
0            CAT          False
1            CAT          False
2            CAT          False
3            CAT           True
4            FUR          False
5            FUR          False
6            FUR          False
7            FUR           True
8            HYG          False
9            HYG          False
```

Then you can do your formatting on those rows.